# UITableViewCells with the wrong IndexPath affected and Animation coordinates trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

### Updated question.

I have an interesting effect in my iOs 7 application. I'm using the storyboard (there is no .xib file for a cell) This is a shopping cart. On click at the "+" button inside a some cell I should hide the label text and show UIView with UIPicker, label and shopping cart button above it.  There are some **SECTIONS** (not rows) with 1 row (It was made for creating some space between cells). But if I touch at the plus button at the **section 2**, **section 7** will affect too. And conversely. Some screenshots attached.

### Before touching at a plus button

[image: Before scrolling]
[image]

### After

[image]
[image]

### The code

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source and delegate

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [itemsTitles_ count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MenuItemCell";
    long row = indexPath.section;

    MenuItemCell *cell        = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.delegate             = self;
    cell.itemTitleLabel.text  = [itemsTitles_ objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.itemDescLabel.text   = [itemsDescriptions_ objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.itemCostLabel.text   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Цена: %@ рублей / шт", [itemsCosts_ objectAtIndex:row]];
    cell.itemImageIView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[itemsImages_ objectAtIndex:row]];
    [cell.itemImageIView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [cell.itemImageIView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];

    [cell.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
    [cell.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [cell.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    //Some code for horizontal picker
    return cell;
}
```

Next is the delegate method from my `MenuItemCell` class.

```
- (void)plusButtonTappedOnCell:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    MenuItemCell *cell =  (MenuItemCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.quantityPickerView setHidden:NO];
    [cell.itemDescLabel setHidden:YES];
    [cell.plusButton setHidden:YES];
}
```

It works if I add

```
[cell.itemDescLabel setHidden:NO];
[cell.plusButton setHidden:NO];
```

to `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. But problem appears again if I add the shopping cart animation. Only works with 1-4 sections.
Where I was wrong?:) Thanks in advance.

### Added

The 1st problem was solved, thx. The second problem came. On the 1st screenshot there is normal animation direction for UIImageView (it works for 1-4 sections). But when I scroll down - the direction becomes a straight line for 5-7 sections. (screenshot 2)

[image]
[image]

### The animation code

```
UIImageView *imgV = cell.itemImageIView;
        CGRect rect = [imgV.superview convertRect:imgV.frame fromView:nil];
        rect = CGRectMake(5, (rect.origin.y*-1)-10, imgV.frame.size.width, imgV.frame.size.height);

        // create new duplicate image
        UIImageView *starView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imgV.image];
        [starView setFrame:rect];
        starView.layer.cornerRadius=10.0f;
        [self.view addSubview:starView];

        // begin ---- apply position animation
        CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
        pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        pathAnimation.duration=0.65;
        pathAnimation.delegate=self;

        // tab-bar right side item frame-point = end point
        CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(210+rect.size.width/2, 390+rect.size.height/2);
        CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, starView.frame.origin.x, starView.frame.origin.y);
        CGPathAddCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, endPoint.x, starView.frame.origin.y, endPoint.x, starView.frame.origin.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
        pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
        CGPathRelease(curvedPath);
        // end ---- apply position animation

        // apply transform animation
        CABasicAnimation *basic=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
        [basic setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(0.25, 0.25, 0.25)]];
        [basic setAutoreverses:NO];
        [basic setDuration:0.65];

        [starView.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"curveAnimation"];
        [starView.layer addAnimation:basic forKey:@"transform"];
```

### SOLVED

End point coordinate:

```
float differenceY = 390 - (cell.frame.size.height * (items_.count - indexPath.section));
        float endY = (cell.frame.origin.y + cell.frame.size.height/2 < 390) ? 390 : differenceY + cell.frame.origin.y + cell.frame.size.height/2;
        CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(210+rect.size.width/2, endY +rect.size.height/2);
```

Start point coordinate:

```
CGRect rect = [imgV.superview convertRect:imgV.frame fromView:nil];
        rect = CGRectMake(5, cell.frame.origin.y + rect.size.height/2, imgV.frame.size.width, imgV.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a matter of reusing the UITableViewCell. 
You should know what item has been tapped so that you can toggle show/hide views: **cell.quantityPickerView**, **cell.itemDescLabel**, **cell.plusButton** 
in method **'tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MenuItemCell";


    MenuItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    //Uncomment if the cell is not declared in the storyboard
    //if (!cell) {
        //cell = [[MenuItemCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.delegate  = self;
        [cell.itemImageIView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [cell.itemImageIView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
        [cell.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
        [cell.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [cell.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    //}

    MenuItem *menuItem = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.itemTitleLabel.text  = menuItem.title;
    cell.itemDescLabel.text   = menuItem.description;
    cell.itemCostLabel.text   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Цена: %@ рублей / шт", menuItem.cost];
    cell.itemImageIView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:menuItem.imageName];

    if (menuItem.isSelected) {
        cell.quantityPickerView.hidden = NO;
        cell.itemDescLabel.hidden = YES;
        cell.plusButton.hidden = YES;
    }
    else {
        cell.quantityPickerView.hidden = YES;
        cell.itemDescLabel.hidden = NO;
        cell.plusButton.hidden = NO;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

By the way for convenience, you should have a class:

```
@interface MenuItem : NSObject

@property (readwrite, nonatomic) BOOL isSelected;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *description;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *imageName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *cost;

@end
```

Then, in method:

```
- (void)plusButtonTappedOnCell:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    MenuItemCell *cell =  (MenuItemCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    MenuItem *menuItem = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (menuItem.isSelected) {
        cell.quantityPickerView.hidden = YES;
        cell.itemDescLabel.hidden = NO;
        cell.plusButton.hidden = NO;
        menuItem.isSelected = NO;
    } else {
        cell.quantityPickerView.hidden = NO;
        cell.itemDescLabel.hidden = YES;
        cell.plusButton.hidden = YES;
        menuItem.isSelected = YES;
    }

}
```

Comment: I've just updated my answer. I assume that you have a property 'items' that contains MenuItem objects.

Comment: Did you layout your cell in the storyboard?

Comment: `plusButtonTappedOnCell:` shouldn't change any hidden properties. It should just change the `isSelected` property, and then reload the row. All the code to describe the appearance of the cell needs to be inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, or you will have these reuse issues.

Comment: Thanks, it's good thoughts, but problem with animation is still alive. And after reloading row with `[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];` for the first time there is some flash and fade animation in UITableViewController.

Comment: @AaronBrager that would be nicer. :D

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in your code, this issue may accur..  Please try this below code inside the table `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.. This will fix the label issue that disappears...

```
MenuItemCell *cell        = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:MenuItemCell owner:self options:Nil];

        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
```

Hope this may help for you..

Comment: I have no xib file for cell, only .h. and .m

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:` is guaranteed to return a cell anyway, so this wouldn't help even if you had a xib.